# WSO2 ESB Statistics and details

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to implement a service that returns a list of proxies, sequences, CARs and other artifacts that are deployed into current ESB instance.

This service is necessary to be sure that all instances are deployed with the same artifacts and have the same versions.

The first solution I found was to check FS inside `$ESB_HOME/repository` but I think that there must be some java interfaces to this information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider wso2 products, most of them are based on carbon platform. Also its includes OSGi bundles or carbon components. You can list all services by running product with -DosgiConsole

Step 01:

first you need to enable carbon setting on ESB/repository/conf/carbon.xml

```
<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```

to

```
<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>true</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```

then start esb with osgi console mod. type

```
listAdminServices
```

to get all enabled admin services and can get hidden services by typing

```
listHiddenServices
```

Step02:

Once you run above commands you can get list of available services. you need to append ?wsdl to listed path to get WSDL of listed service.

ex:

https://:8243/services/SequenceAdminService/

to

https://:8243/services/SequenceAdminService?wsdl

Then you can invoke service using any secure client.